# R on ubuntu 16: unable to load shared object, undefined symbol: gotoblas

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, installation

I am on the [Amazon Deep Learning AMI image](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B06VSPXKDX) trying to use R.

`$ which R` returns

`/usr/bin/R`

`$ R` returns

`/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libblas.so.3: undefined symbol: gotoblas`

`sudo update-alternatives --config libblas.so.3` returns 4 possible selections:

`/usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3`, `/usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3`, `/usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3` and `/usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3`

By selecting option 2 I can get into the R repl.  However, I receieve the following warning:

`unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3: undefined symbol: gotoblas`

This same error causes package installations to fail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please complain to whoever put that AMI together as Goto BLAS has not been used on Debian/Ubuntu for quite some time. I happen to be the respective maintainer for the R binary, and it looks like you may have gotten damaged goods. Or maybe you just messed it up: as a user you should generally never ever touch `update-alternatives`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! I followed [this post](http://blog.nguyenvq.com/blog/2014/11/10/optimized-r-and-python-standard-blas-vs-atlas-vs-openblas-vs-mkl/) and used `sudo update-alternatives --config liblapack.so.3` to switch to the correct BLAS version.